# LookupError Выдаёт ошибку: No installed app with label 'admin'

Tags: python, django

Выдаёт ошибку:

> LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'blog'
    ]
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.shortcuts import reverse
    from django.utils.text import slugify
    from time import time

    def gen_slug(s):
        new_slug = slugify(s, allow_unicode=True)
        return new_slug + '-' + str(int(time()))


    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
        body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def get_update_url(self):
            return reverse('post_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def  save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.id:
                self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        def get_delete_url(self):
            return reverse('post_delete_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Tag(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def get_update_url(self):
            return render('tag_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def get_delete_url(self):
            return reverse('tag_delete_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

urls.py(приложения blog):

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [
        # Post block
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),     # Posts list
        path('post/create/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_create_url'),     # Post create
        path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),     # Post detail
        path('post/<str:slug>/update/', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post_update_url'),     # Post update

        # Tag block
        path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),     # Tags list
        path('tag/create/', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),     # Tag create
        path('tag/<str:slug>/', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url'),     # Tag detail
        path('tag/<str:slug>/update/', TagUpdate.as_view(), name='tag_update_url'),     # Tag update
        path('tag/<str:slug>/delete/', TagDelete.as_view(), name='tag_delete_url')     # Tag delete
    ]
```

urls.py(главный):

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from django.urls import include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
    ]
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
    from django.views.generic import View
    from django.urls import reverse
    from .models import Post, Tag
    from .utils import *
    from .forms import TagForm, PostForm

    # List block
    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})

    def tags_list(request):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})


    # Detail block
    class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Post
        template = 'blog/post_detail.html'


    class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Tag
        template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'


    # Create block
    class TagCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
        model_form = TagForm
        template = 'blog/tag_create.html'


    class PostCreate(ObjectCreateMixin, View):
        model_form = PostForm
        template = 'blog/post_create_form.html'


    # Update block
    class PostUpdate(ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
        model = Post
        model_form = PostForm
        template = 'blog/post_update_form.html'


    class TagUpdate(ObjectUpdateMixin, View):
        model = Tag
        model_form = TagForm
        template = 'blog/tag_update_form.html'


    # Delete block
    class TagDelete(ObjectDeleteMixin, View):
        model = Tag
        template = 'blog/tag_delete_form'
        redirect_url = 'tags_list_url'
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/faz1l/Desktop/NBlog/app/NBlog/NBlog/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "/home/faz1l/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку где когда?

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку при запуске сервера

Comment: Полный текст ошибки в студию

Comment: Это и есть полный текст ошибки: LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

Comment: Ровно одна строчка и ни строчкой больше? Обычно ошибка занимает несколько десятков строк. Чем и как вы запускаете этот код, что у вас получилась всего одна строчка?

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас скину всё что выдаёт сервер.

Comment: Теперь выдаёт другую ошибку. Сейчас её скину.

Comment: IndentationError означает, что у вас в коде неправильно расставлены отступы. Перечитайте внимательно проблемный файл.

Comment: Теперь выдаёт новую ошибку.